# Outlook JS Add-in - How to remove an add-in after development is done?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have the issue that I cannot remove the developed add-in from Outlook.

To test the add-in I used the `npm run start` command and stopped it with `npm run stop`.
But the add-in is still shown on Outlook Desktop and Outlook Web.

[image]
[image]

I already tried this solutions from the Microsoft forum ([Remove an Add-in from 365 Mail that does not show up in the My Add-ins](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/remove-an-add-in-from-365-mail-that-does-not-show/1eb6cacd-2585-4bf1-8a91-919d6fe6d381)). But the two add-ins does not show up in the add-in list and the "Options" menu is not visible in Outlook online.

[image]
[image]

I already tried cleaning the add-in cache. But then the add-in still appears after some time.

I have a suspicion that the add-in is stored somewhere in my mailbox.

Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Open the manifest of the add-in and get the `<Id>` GUID. Then use a text editor that can search multiiple files (like NotePad++ or TextPad) to search the C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming folder to see if it is mentioned anywhere in that folder. Also open the Windows Registry Editor and see if the GUID is in any keys or values of the registry.

Comment: Also, if there's another Windows computer where you can login with the same identity you were using to create the add-in, please login on that other computer and see if the add-in shows up on the Outlook ribbon there.

Comment: What is the method you followed for installation and removal of this addin. To help understand the scenario, please list the steps that you followed for each platform.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I followed [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) and used `npm run start` to install / run it. I work on Windows 10 Enterprise and use Microsoft® Outlook® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2307 Build 16.0.16626.20170) 64 Bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
My mailbox belongs to a company organisation and they did not assign the role "My Custom Apps". In that case I could sideload the add-ins via npm run start but I could not see them in "My Add-Ins". After the Exchange admin assigned me that role, I could see and remove them in the "My Custom Apps" section.
[Specify the administrators and users who can install and manage add-ins for Outlook in Exchange Online | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/specify-who-can-install-and-manage-add-ins#user-roles)